# I have a javascript countdown but i need the countdown to grab the date from my sql database

Tags: php, javascript, database, echo

I have a countdown for my page to countdown from a certain date in mysql database however I have no idea how to get the date from the database onto the javascript, I have echo'd the date onto the webpage just need to get it into the code and countdown from there now. Any help would be great. Thanks

This is my javascript

```
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2)
s = "0" + s;
return "<b>" + s + "</b>";
}


function CountBack(secs) {
if (secs < 0) {
document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;


return;
}
DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(secs,86400,100000));
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));

document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = DisplayStr;
if (CountActive)
setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
}

function putspan(backcolor, forecolor) {
document.write("<span id='cntdwn' style='background-color:" + backcolor +
            "; color:" + forecolor + "'></span>");
}

if (typeof(BackColor)=="undefined")
BackColor = "white";
if (typeof(ForeColor)=="undefined")
ForeColor= "black";
if (typeof(TargetDate)=="undefined")
TargetDate = "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";
 if (typeof(DisplayFormat)=="undefined")
 DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
 if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined")
 CountActive = true;
 if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined")
 FinishMessage = "";
 if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number")
 CountStepper = -1;
 if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined")
 LeadingZero = true;
 CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
 if (CountStepper == 0)
 CountActive = false;
 var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
 putspan(BackColor, ForeColor);
 var dthen = new Date(TargetDate);
 var dnow = new Date();
 if(CountStepper>0)
 ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
 else
 ddiff = new Date(dthen-dnow);
 gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
 CountBack(gsecs);
```

THIS IS MY CODE IN THE HTML

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 TargetDate = "4/17/2012 23:41";
 BackColor = "white";
 ForeColor = "black";
 CountActive = true;
 CountStepper = -1;
 LeadingZero = true;
 DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Day, %%H%% Hour, %%M%% Minute, %%S%% Second ";
 FinishMessage = "Auction Ended";
 </script>
```

Comment: so you want to echo date from mysql and assign it to TargetDate?

Comment: yeah thats pretty much but ill need it to be in the DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS format

Comment: how does you php code looks like in terms getting query from database? so i can give you an exact answer.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT enddate FROM property WHERE propertyID = '1'";
    $queryresult = mysql_query($sql)
    or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)){
 $enddate=$row['enddate'];

 
 echo "$enddate <br/>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html file should be actually php an which you first call your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT enddate FROM property WHERE propertyID = '1'"; 
$queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult))
{ $enddate=$row['enddate']; }
```

then you format your date as:

```
$enddate = date("j/m/Y H:i",strtotime($enddate));
```

then after php code you have your html code and you print date as:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 TargetDate = "<?php echo $enddate; ?>";
 BackColor = "white";
 ForeColor = "black";
 CountActive = true;
 CountStepper = -1;
 LeadingZero = true;
 DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Day, %%H%% Hour, %%M%% Minute, %%S%% Second ";
 FinishMessage = "Auction Ended";
 </script>
```